# Which files do I have to back up to not lose my Security Key?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic, android

I am using the Security Application for Android via [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) so I get the extra 100 Cartel Points per Month. This works fine, but I had to enter multiple codes into the app and the account to make it work, which is normal.
Now in case I reinstall my Operating System, which files would I need to back up to keep my security key on my account and not having to go through support to remove it?

Comment: Just save the serial and recovery code.

Comment: @Ramhound You could write up how to get them and put it into an answer if you like.

Comment: You need the serial and activation code and the password of you entered that you wrote all that down write ?

Comment: @Ramhound What?

Comment: You have to enter a serial and activation code.  This means you can install the same authenticator to multiple devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no files that you need to back up.

The serial number and activation code that you used to activate the application the first time will be same code you enter when you set it up again.

Comment: But what if you didn't save it somewhere? Is there a way to look at it again? Sorry if I am stupid here, but I can't find it.

Comment: You should be able to find it in the Information tab or settings. I stopped playing a while ago so I don't remember exactly where it is.